# File I/O Stream Vs (ImageIO.read OR ImageIO.write) method

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

What is the difference and advantages between writing or reading a image from file I/O Stream Vs `ImageIO.read` OR write function??

Is there certain operation in which we cannot write an image using ImageIO method??

Comment: `ImageIO.read` and `ImageIO.write` are utility methods to load and save images easily. They actually use `Stream`s to access the files.

Comment: @Bubletan-- so ImageIO.read and ImageIO.write are one step ahead ?
Can we do this program using utility I/O functions http://www.javabeat.net/java-compress-image/

Comment: Well, in a way yes. They are way simpler to use for image I/O, but you still need the streams for other things.

Comment: @Bubletan- have you seen above link?Can you change above code using imageio read/write?

Comment: It's already using `ImageIO` to read and write the images, but without accessing the `ImageOutputStream`, we can't change its settings.

Comment: why imageoutput stream is similar to ImageIO.write?? so are you sure that it cannot be done without it?

Comment: `ImageOutputStream` is pretty much a part of `ImageIO`.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges. A `FileInputStream` gives you bytes, not an image. `ImageIO.read()` gives you an image.